# Splitting/Tokenizing a sentence into string words with special conditions

Tags: regex, python-3.x, nlp, tokenize

I am trying to implement a tokenizer to split string of words.

The special conditions I have are: split punctuation . , ! ? into a separate string
and split any characters that have a space in them i.e. `I have a dog!'-4@` -> `'I', 'have', 'a' , 'dog', !, "'-4@"`

Something like this.....

I don't plan on trying the nltk's package, and I have looked at `re.split` and `re.findall`, yet for both cases:
`re.split` = I don't know how to split out words with punctuation next to them such as 'Dog,'
`re.findall` = Sure it prints out all the matched string, but what about the unmatched ones?

IF you guys have any suggestions, I'd be very happy to try them.

Comment: Pick a specific python version, or leave agnostic: don't pick _both_ 2.x and 3.x unless such is actually relevant to the question/problem.

Answer (score 1):

Are you trying to split on a delimiter(punctuation) while keeping it in the final results? One way of doing that would be this:

```
import re
import string

sent = "I have a dog!'-4@"
punc_Str = str(string.punctuation)

print(re.split(r"([.,;:!^ ])", sent))
```

This is the result I get.

```
['I', ' ', 'have', ' ', 'a', ' ', 'dog', '!', "'-4@"]
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
re.findall(r'[a-z]+|[.!?]|(?:(?![.!?])\S)+', txt, re.I)
```

Alternatives in the regex:

- `[a-z]+` - a non-empty sequence of letters (ignore case),
- `[.!?]` - any (single) char from your list (note that between brackets
  neither a *dot* nor a '?' need to be quoted),
- `(?:(?![.!?])\S)+` - a non-empty sequence of non-white characters,
  other than in your list.

E.g. for text containing `I have a dog!'-4@?.` the result is:

```
['I', 'have', 'a', 'dog', '!', "'-4@", '?', '.']
```